# Cloud Deploying a Scheduled Task

Tags: wolfram-cloud, scheduling, apifunction

#### cross-posted on the [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/888492) forum

I am trying to deploy a `ScheduledTask` that monitors the state of a google spread sheet every hour. I want the object to display the content (which should be static), but instead upon deployment, it creates an object which redirects me to a notepad in my *Wolfram* Development Platform account that allows me to add information (but cannot execute). Here is a look at my code:

This imports the contents of the google doc:

```
Clear@url
Clear@csv
(url = "https://path-to-google-doc/export?format=csv") //
Import[#, "CSV", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"] & //
Flatten@# & //
(csv = #) & //
Dataset@# &
```

Which results in an output that takes the form: `Dataset[{....}]`.

To create the `ScheduledTask`, I have tried:

```
Clear@obj
obj = ScheduledTask[{Now, csv}, "Hourly"](*creates a scheduled task that monitors the information in the doc every hour*)//
CloudDeploy[#, Permissions -> "Public"] &
```

Again, this results in a redirect to my development platform account (that is only accessible to me and not anyone else) and not to a static web object which displays the contents of the google doc. I am pretty new to using the *Wolfram Cloud*, but it feels a lot like a black box, which makes debugging pretty difficult because I am never sure where the issue truly lies; my thought is to wrap the scheduled task in an `APIFunction`, but I am not sure how to go about doing that, since there is no specific association I am looking to make for the information in the csv file. Is this the right way to go about this? How can I utilize `APIFunction` if I don't have an explicit set of rules I am looking to make?

**Update**: I've tried including the line of code before `CloudDeploy` of `RunScheduledTask[#]&` as well as `StartScheduledTask[#]&`. When deployed, this results in a static web object like I'd wanted, but the former gives me [this](https://www.business-laboratory.wolframcloud.com/objects/2ca2b0a2-85fd-4aa7-950a-d5fc3ebf4893), and the latter gives me [this](https://www.business-laboratory.wolframcloud.com/objects/a5c9dd62-92c4-4cdf-adcd-ca1f21643dac). Again, I don't like that I can't really see what's going on in the Cloud that results in it failing.

Comment: To run a scheduled task you will apparently need a $100/month Producer account. I'd guess that there isn't anyone answering questions on StackExchange who has access to such an account. On the other hand, a Producer account comes with both email and phone Wolfram support.

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock Good point, and one that I hadn't realized. I always like to ask the community first before emailing directly, you never know if your solution can help someone else later on; do you think I'd have a better chance of this being addressed in the _Wolfram_ Community forums?

Comment: Yes, your solution certainly will be of interest to all Wolfram Development Platform users, especially because it helps to establish the case for upgrading to a Producer account verses using an external service. See also  this [advice](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/367/is-there-any-special-kind-of-crossposting-netiquette-for-se-mathgroup-etc/1887#1887) about cross-posting.

Answer (score 2):

**I am not sure how many of y'all have been keeping up with the Community discussion, but there are some key updates I wanted to summarize here:**

1. `ScheduledTask` does not store values; it is essentially a block of code that produces a result which it then discards. `AutoRefreshed` works better wrt deployment of tasks to the *Wolfram Cloud* because `AutoRefreshed` objects will store a value and repeatedly update it according to the given schedule.
2. Functions like `RunScheduledTask` and `StartScheduledTask` do not perform on Cloud objects like you would expect them to, and will likely be deprecated. (Personally, as a result of the current technical discussion, I also think that the added flexibility of `AutoRefreshed` will result in it becoming the de facto function in place of `ScheduledTask`).
3. `GenerateHTTPResponse` is a good function to use if you are unable/do not want to `CloudDeploy`, but would like to see if it is at least possible, because it simulates the behavior of the *Wolfram Cloud* server

Comment: Wolfram Development Platform [pricing](http://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/pricing/) lists scheduled tasks, which presumably include `AutoRefreshed`, at the $100/month Producer price point. Have you upgraded your account to this level?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock yes, the company I work for uses their own Private Cloud, so we should have all these features I am trying to make use of

Comment: OK great! Are you working with Wolfram support on a solution to the `AuotRefreshed` problem that you mention in your most recent Wolfram Community [post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/890545)?

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock yes, I am! The solution that support suggested is very similar to the piece of code that Dylan posted, which acts as a nice template to get started with.

Comment: After you get something working I assume that you will post your code on the Wolfram Community, where I agree with Andrew de Laix that even big fans of `Postfix` notation and pure functions should eliminate the `Postfix` and keep the number of pure functions to an absolute minimum. I look forward to reading about your solution!

Comment: @ChristopherHaydock yes that's correct. I primarily use `Postfix` notation for development purposes (which is mostly what I'm doing): it's a great way to deal with debugging! For the finished solution I'll try to make it a bit more polished